# schema based on element type and name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an xsd that defines a Parameter element. I can't change the xsd file.

```
   <xsd:complexType name="Parameter">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                <xsd:element name="string" type="StringParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="boolean" type="BooleanParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="ubyte" type="UnsignedByteParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="hex_value" type="HexParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="double" type="DoubleParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="long" type="LongParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="ulong" type="UnsignedLongParameter"/>
                <xsd:element name="int" type="IntParameter"/>
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required"/>
        <xsd:attribute name="type" type="xsd:string" use="optional"/>
        <!-- multiplicty changed in GEMS 1.2 per issue 15495 -->
        <xsd:attribute name="multiplicity" type="xsd:int" use="optional" />
    </xsd:complexType>
```

My program will be getting xml data with these "Parameter"s

```
 <Parameter name="frame_length">
   <long>1024</long>
 </Parameter>
 <Parameter name=”ports”>
   <int>10001</int>
   <int>10002</int>
 </Parameter>
```

I'm new to xml and I cannot figure if it is possible to write an xsd to define different types of "Parameters". A Parameter called frame_length must have 1 long. A Parameter call ports must have 2 ints.

Comment: Are you using XSD 1.0 or XSD 1.1? I think you can only do that in XSD 1.1. I answered some days ago [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25082505/restriction-of-elements-based-on-another-attribute-using-xsd-1-1) quite similar to yours.

Comment: XSD 1.0. I've come to the conclusion that its not possible in 1.0

Comment: OK, XSD 1.1 rules :D